# Best way to intercept pressing of Caps Lock

Tags: winapi, setwindowshookex, capslock

What is the best way to intercept the Caps Lock button on Windows, for making a program like Launchy?

Currently, I'm setting a low-level hook with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990.aspx), but that's a bit too low-level for me, since I don't want to intercept other programs that are trying to be active a low level. I'm looking for the highest possible level of interception that can still prevent turning on Caps Lock itself... any better suggestions?

Comment: lol, what? How would that help/work??

Comment: actually it's pretty simple to do, just call an interrupt and mask the bit you need

Comment: ... in Win32 user-mode? Never knew you could do that...

Comment: @Mehrdad: actually i'm stuck with console apps, so 16 bit..

Comment: @BlackBear: Then that doesn't answer my question... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the best way *is* to use a low-level hook, since `RegisterHotkey` doesn't *intercept* the key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
RegisterHotKey(hWnd, 0, 0, VK_CAPITAL);
```

Your window will receive a `WM_HOTKEY` message whenever this key is pressed.

Comment: This doesn't prevent Caps Lock from toggling its state -- it's too high-level. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's true, but you can't "prevent" this without using a hook. You can however process the hotkey and reset the state using [`SetKeyboardState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646314%28VS.85%29.aspx), but using a hook will be more efficient.

Comment: Ah, so there's no other way? Is there any higher-level hook than a low-level keyboard hook that I could use, or is that my last (and only) option?

Comment: @Mehrdad: None that I'm aware of. But is there a reason you don't want to use low-level hooks?

Comment: Oh, I can definitely do that (and that's what I'm already doing, as I mentioned in my post). The problem is I just don't need this much power -- I don't want my program to intercept the caps lock key before other low-level programs, like virtual machines. But if there's no other options then I'll try this.